# Reduce time it takes for device to power on when pressing power button?

Tags: power-on, buttons

I recently got my Nexus 7, and I love it.

There is only one thing that is bugging me: The amount of time you have to hold the power button to turn the device on.

Most of time I have to hold it for around 30 seconds - this is not ideal at all, as number 1, my finger starts hurting as I am pushing it in and 2 my finger easily slips meaning I have to start again!

SO, my question is this:

Is there any way, without flashing a custom ROM, to reduce the amount of time I have to hold the power button to power the device on? Flashing a custom kernel **is ok**.

Comment: It could be by hardware design, not related to kernels or anything... maybe the gap between the power button and the spring-coil to trigger the signal is big.. And yes, Nexus 7 is known for that (check android subreddit about that!), flashing won't work either!

Comment: @t0mm13b There must be *some* way to change it. It really bugs me, and is a design bug in my opinion...

Comment: Read this discussion: http://forums.androidcentral.com/google-nexus-7-tablet-forum/219910-normal-time-you-have-hold-down-power-button-turn-please-help.html

Comment: Unless you're prepared to dismantle it, no flashing or software is a substitute for it! unfortunately!

Comment: When you push in the button you can feel the switch click, it's just holding it there - it is exactly the same with the Galaxy Nexus and the Nexus 4, it's just something I have become accustomed to now

Comment: All my other devices power on within 5 seconds :(

Comment: "Most of time I have to hold it for around 30 seconds", whoa, really? I have a Galaxy Nexus and it's nowhere close to 30 seconds. Is this normal?

Comment: @bigbadonk420 Yes, really. It does vary, however sometimes it takes 3 seconds of holding it down to power on.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer:

This is something set at a really low level and I have never heard of this as being something that can be modified.

It's definitely nothing that can be resolved in a custom rom, maybe a different bootloader, but I have a feeling it's at a lower level than that.