# Reduce power button holding duration to turn on the device

Tags: power-on, samsung-galaxy-a3

It takes 4 seconds of holding the power button to turn on my Samsung Galaxy A03 on Android 13.

Can I change this to 2 seconds?

Comment: Usually the feature to turn on your phone via power button is implemented in hardware without an possibility to configure it. But I am not familiar with your phone so I don't know if this is also true for Galaxy A03.

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. We have a similar question asked already: [Reduce time it takes for device to power on when pressing power button?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/38161/44325). Samsung doesn't seem to provide such settings, so the only possibility is an out-of-the-box solution. However, I don't know if such methods exist (custom ROM? kernel flashing?)

Comment: Thank you for answering!